# Django autoroute

Tags: django, model-view-controller, django-urls

With ASP.NET MVC, I can just add an action to a view and it will automagically work. Django seems to make me write every route in the urls.py table - is there a way to make it map, for example "/foo/bar" to `foo.views.bar` without me explicitly saying so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason django makes you write everything is something along these lines: [What's wrong with "magic"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441717/whats-wrong-with-magic/442088#442088)

Secondly, the map you are suggesting makes it difficult to deal with arguments to the view functions.  The simplest would be to enforce by convention that all views only use `GET` and `POST` arguments and otherwise take some standard set of arguments (e.g. `request`, `template_name`).

To implement this map you want, you can iterate over your views module and generate the patterns object.  Mind you, this is a really ugly hack and largely defeats the purpose of the url mapper. In `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

import myapp.views

urlpatterns = patterns('myapp.views',                                                                                                                                   
    *map(lambda x: url(r'^myapp/%s/$' % x, x, name='myapp_%s' % x),
         [k for k,v in myapp.views.__dict__.items() if callable(v)]))
```

Comment: Hmm, I would've thought this fits in with DRY. I'll try your hack.